# Failover connection string in n-tier linq2sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

Scenario: ASP.Net web app (n-tier linq2sql) on local IIS  with connection to SQL 2008 database over VPN.  Some data is replicated to a local SQL 2008 express DB (different name).  If the connection is down to VPN database, we would like to use the local instance for some parts of the web app.

My Question is, how can the following solution be improved. we have involves a lot of passing the connection string about.  If this involved mirroring, we could set the failover partner but as it is a different database I don't think this is possible.

Current Code:

Check if we can connect remotely, put the working connection string in session

```
Session_Start()
{
//if can connect to remote db
Session["ConnStr"] = //remote connection
//else
Session["ConnStr"] = //local connection
}
```

Pass connection string in UI to BLL

```
        protected void ods1_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        TestManager myTestManager = new TestManager(Session["ConnString"].ToString());
        e.ObjectInstance = myTestManager;
    }
```

Pass to DAL

```
    public class TestManager
{
       private readonly string _connectionString;

       public TestManager(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
    public List<Test> GetAll()
    {
        TestDB testDB = new TestDB(_connectionString);
        return testDB.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Set connection in DAL creating DataContext in constructor

```
public class TestDB
{
    public TestDB(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _dbContext = new TestDataContext(_connectionString);
    }
    private TestDataContext _dbContext;

    private string _connectionString;

    public string ConnectionString

    {
        get
        {
            return _connectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            _connectionString = value;
        }
    }

    public TestDataContext DbContext
    {
        get
        {
            return _dbContext;
        }
        set
        {
            _dbContext = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Test> GetAll()
    {
        var query = from t in DbContext.Tests
                    select new DTO.Test()
                    {
                        Id = t.Id,
                        Name = t.Name

                    };

        return query.ToList();


    }
```

Comment: I've edited it slightly for clarity.  I'm looking for a better way which doesn't involve passing the connection string about like this and in checking the connection and swapping it over.  It may be that what I'm doing is the only way but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: Should the connection string be stored/resolved in the UI layer?  That is a DAL concern only I would think?  Have the context provide a static method which returns an instance of the context.  In that method, determine which database is available?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way of doing it, and what you have is not abnormal even if you aren't doing connection redirects.  Dependency injecting the connection string is not a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave it at this then.